# AWS Comprehend Medical: Invalid Signature Exception Error (JavaScriptv3, Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, medical

I am trying to learn how to use AWS's Comprehend Medical Tool and I am not exactly sure why I am getting this InvalidSignatureException. I am new to using AWS tools for reference. Below is my index.js file and my package.json file. I setup my AWS credentials in a shared file on my computer with the access key and secret access key.

index.js file: Where I create the client and try to access the detectEntities() function from an example text that I got from the Comprehend Medical webpage.

```
import {S3Client} from "@aws-sdk/client-s3"
import * as AWS from "@aws-sdk/client-s3"
import {ComprehendMedicalClient, DetectEntitiesV2Command} from "@aws-sdk/client-comprehendmedical";
import {fromIni} from "@aws-sdk/credential-providers"
//AWS.config.loadFromPath('./config.json');

// const REGION = "us-east-2";
//const s3Client = new S3Client(config);

const client = new ComprehendMedicalClient({
    credentials: fromIni({profile: 'default'}),
    region: "us-east-2"
});

const input = {
    Text: "Pt is 87 yo woman, highschool teacher with past medical history that includes - status post cardiac catheterization in April 2019. She presents today palpitations and chest pressure. HPI: Sleeping trouble on present dosage of Clonidine. Severe Rash on face and leg, slightly itchy. Meds: Vyvanse 50 mgs po at breakfast daily, Clonidine 0.2 mgs -- 1 and 1 / 2 tabs po qhs. HEENT: Boggy inferior turbinates, No oropharyngeal lesion. Lungs : clear. Heart : Regular rhythm. Skin :  Mild erythematous eruption to hairline. Follow-up as scheduled"
};

const command = new DetectEntitiesV2Command(input);
const response = await client.send(command);
console.log(response);
```

package.json file: where I set the dependencies for the project

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-comprehendmedical": "^3.349.0",
    "@aws-sdk/credential-providers": "^3.350.0",
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.32.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mysql2": "^3.3.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22"
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```

Error Message:

```
const response = new exceptionCtor({
                     ^

InvalidSignatureException: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
    at throwDefaultError (C:\Users\shubh\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\Medical App Example\server\node_modules\@aws-sdk\smithy-client\dist-cjs\default-error-handler.js:8:22)     
    at C:\Users\shubh\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\Medical App Example\server\node_modules\@aws-sdk\smithy-client\dist-cjs\default-error-handler.js:18:39
    at de_DetectEntitiesV2CommandError (C:\Users\shubh\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\Medical App Example\server\node_modules\@aws-sdk\client-comprehendmedical\dist-cjs\protocols\Aws_json1_1.js:491:20)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async C:\Users\shubh\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\Medical App Example\server\node_modules\@aws-sdk\middleware-serde\dist-cjs\deserializerMiddleware.js:7:24
    at async C:\Users\shubh\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\Medical App Example\server\node_modules\@aws-sdk\middleware-signing\dist-cjs\awsAuthMiddleware.js:14:20
    at async C:\Users\shubh\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\Medical App Example\server\node_modules\@aws-sdk\middleware-retry\dist-cjs\retryMiddleware.js:27:46
    at async C:\Users\shubh\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\Medical App Example\server\node_modules\@aws-sdk\middleware-logger\dist-cjs\loggerMiddleware.js:7:26
    at async file:///C:/Users/shubh/OneDrive/Desktop/Projects/Medical%20App%20Example/server/index.js:20:18 {       
  '$fault': 'client',
    httpStatusCode: 400,
    requestId: '5c6416f9-5c59-4da8-9842-cd4e39bd4886',
    extendedRequestId: undefined,
    cfId: undefined,
    attempts: 1,
    totalRetryDelay: 0
  },
  __type: 'InvalidSignatureException'
}
```

I already looked through the documentation that AWS provides and YouTube videos and I kinda lost on how Comprehend Medical works and how AWS works in general. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here are the resources I already looked through:

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gwLtwW1MUTQ&t=1s - unfortunately this video uses v2 of the JavaScript SDK and not v3, so there are some differences in how to implement the client I believe.
2. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-shared.html - this just helped me understand how to setup the shared credentials file and how that works
3. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pdfs/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/js-sdk-dg.pdf - tried to implement and understand how other AWS services are used however I got confused.
4. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ComprehendMedical.html - I also looked through this documentation, and I am not sure how to fix the error I am getting using the information given here.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the issue by creating a new IAM user that had the correct policies attached to it. Had to attach the following policies when creating the user: AmazonSNSFullAccess, AmazonS3FullAccess, ComprehendMedicalFullAccess, AdministratorAccess.